# Proper way to handle external versioning with Node client.update()

Tags: elasticsearch

**Scenario:**

We're synching part of our Firestore database to an ElasticSearch instance. We're using external versioning with some timestamp in milliseconds as version number.

**What we're doing:**

- When a new document is created in Firestore, or when we need to completely overwrite a document, we're synching by calling the **INDEX API**, which works as expected.
  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_index
  Note it does include parameters for `version` and `version_type` (which we're setting as `external`).
- When we only need to update a specific field, we're calling the **UPDATE API**:
  https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html#_update
  We expected it to include `version` and `version_type` as well, but it **does not** include those parameters. Not setting external versioning is causing the call to return an error:

  `Validation Failed: 1: internal versioning can not be used for optimistic concurrency control. Please use if_seq_no and if_primary_term instead`

**The problem:**

We don't have `seq_no` nor `primary_term` at hand. We're counting on optimistic concurrency control based on external versioning by the Firestore update timestamp in milliseconds.

The specific field to update is a calculation that's not even part of the original document in Firestore, so simply overwriting the whole document to ES every time is not an option. We do need to update only one field in ES.

**And... the questions:**

- Why doesn't the **update API** include `version` and `version_type`? Maybe we're missing something about the concept and this is not the correct approach at all.
- If `version` and `version_type` are out of the **update API** on purpose... what could be the correct approach for this situation? Since we're using external versioning, `seq_no` and `primary_term` were not supposed to be relevant. Saving information back to Firebase from ES is just cumbersome for what we need.

The client is @elastic/elasticsearch: 7.9.0 in Node, in case that matters.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There's a PR about this which has been merged into [main branch](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/bulk-updates-not-respecting--version/14134/5), not sure why this change is NOT merged into other branches, do you have solutions for this?

Comment: @JerryChin Not really. This is an old project and at that moment we decided to extract the properties to update (some short arrays) into a separate index. So we're synching the whole main document and their attached lists by separate. Very inefficient but worked on this case for us. Not what we wanted, definitively.

Comment: @JerryChin BTW, thanks for the info about the PR. In newer projects we're always synching the whole document, even for a tiny property update. If there's a possibility to sync that property only (while keeping the versioning), that'd be much more efficient, and also convenient for new data structure designs. I'll take a look at it.